# SQL Adding and substracting one to an ID in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I'm new to Teradata and recently at work I've been reading a stored procedure, in which the following select is executed.

```
    SELECT  A.DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE_DEF_ID,
        A.DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE,
        A.END_DT,
        .
        .
        .
        B.DUMMY_CLASS_LVL9_CDE,
        B.DUMMY_CLASS_LVL9_DESC,
        C.DUMMY_CLASS_LVL8_CDE,
        C.DUMMY_CLASS_LVL8_DESC,
        D.DUMMY_CLASS_LVL7_CDE,
        D.DUMMY_CLASS_LVL7_DESC,
        -- ETC
FROM    DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE_DEF A,
        DUMMY_CLASS_LVL9 B,
        DUMMY_CLASS_LVL7 C,
        .
        .
        .
        -- ETC
WHERE   A.DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE_DEF_ID = B.DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE_DEF_ID
AND     C.DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE_DEF_ID +1 -1 = B.DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE_DEF_ID
AND     C.DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE_LVL9_CDE = B.DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE_LVL9_CDE
AND     D.DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE_DEF_ID = C.DUMMY_CLASS_TYPE_DEF_ID +1 -1
```

I haven't seen this before and I want to know why is adding and substracting one from the ID, and then checking if it is equal to the ID in another table. I don't see the difference between adding and substracting one, from not doing that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `+0` was an old trick to confuse an optimizer, to prevent index usage. Now as the Teradata optimizer got smarter and eliminates the calculation, they might have switched to `+1 -1` (which is still not opimized) to get a different preparation for a join.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much for your answer.